Class of countably join-complete lattices is not closed under ultraproduct
I need to prove the above claim by constructing a counterexample. My intuition is that $\mathcal{A}_n = \langle A, \leq \rangle$ where $A = (0, 1, \ldots, n)$ should work, but cannot verify why. Any help is appreciated.

Your intuition is good! A more "logic"-y way to get a foothold on your ultraproduct is to think about which first-order sentences it satisfies. In particular it must be a total order, and the sentences "every element other than the smallest one has a predecessor" and "every element other than the largest one has a successor" must hold in it. It follows from this that if it's not finite it cannot be countably join-complete. This is closely related to David's nice answer.

Take $e_n$ to be the element of ultraproduct represented by the sequence $(0, \cdots, 0, n, n, \cdots)$ with $n$ zeros at the front. I claim that $\{e_n\}$ does not admit a supremum. Indeed, given any $(a_m)_{\mathcal{U}}$, it is larger than or equal to all $e_n$ iff there exists, for each $n$, a set $A_n \in \mathcal{U}$ s.t. $a_m \geq n$ for all $m \in A_n$. Thus, if $(a_m)_{\mathcal{U}}$ is larger than or equal to all $e_n$, then so does $(a_m - 1)_{\mathcal{U}}$ (just choose $A’_n = A_{n+1}$). But $(a_m - 1)_{\mathcal{U}} < (a_m)_{\mathcal{U}}$. So no supremum of $\{e_n\}$ exists.

Here $\mathcal{U}$ is the ultrafilter, right?

@DavetheSid Yes. This works for any free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$.
